Limit of ratio of two equivalent sequences
I was working through a proof of the Cartan's closed subgroup theorem, from Lie Theory.
I got stuck in a passage when sequences of real numbers are used.
I don't think I need to give you all of the details (the fully formalised proof is several pages long). I will do my best to explain the issue and be self-contained.
First, fix $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, any real number.
Consider then $\{a_n \, / \, b_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of rational approximations of $\lambda$:
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb N, \quad a_n \, / \, b_n \in \mathbb Q, \quad \lim_{n \to \infty } a_n \, / \, b_n = \lambda.$$
Secondly, we are already given $\{t_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$, a sequence of strictly positive real numbers, with limit zero:
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb N, \quad t_n > 0, \quad \lim_{n \to \infty } t_n = 0.$$
Then, pick $\{p_n \, / \, q_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ a sequence of better and better rational approximations of $t_n$:
$$ \forall n \in \mathbb N, \quad p_n \, / \, q_n \in \mathbb Q, \quad \lim_{n \to \infty } \Big \lvert  \frac{p_n}{q_n} - t_n \Big \rvert = 0.$$
I think this could be done, for instance, by taking the decimal expansion of $t_n$ and truncating it to one digit more every time.
I guess the right wording is that $\{p_n \, / \, q_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $\{t_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ are equivalent sequences.
Finally, set $m_n = \Big \lfloor \frac{a_n}{b_n} \frac{q_n}{p_n} \Big \rfloor$. Now we have a sequence of integer values.
We need to show that:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} m_n t_n = \lambda.$$
What did I try so far?
I first tried proving the claim without the floor brackets, to make everything easier, hoping  I would have been able to apply the squeeze theorem later on.
That is to say, I tried to prove that:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \frac{q_n}{p_n} t_n = \lambda.$$
I noticed that in order to prove this, it is enough to prove that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{q_n}{p_n} t_n = 1.$$
In fact, if we already knew this, we could do the computation the following way:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \frac{q_n}{p_n} t_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{q_n}{p_n} t_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} \cdot 1 = \lambda \cdot 1 = \lambda.$$
This is why I chose that title; because I think the main question is the following.
If $\{p_n \, / \, q_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $\{t_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ are equivalent (in the sense that the limit of their distances is zero), morally they become equal, in the limit.
But can we also entail that the limit of their ratios is one?
In symbols:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } \Big \lvert  \frac{p_n}{q_n} - t_n \Big \rvert = 0 \overset{?}{\implies}  \lim_{n \to \infty }\frac{p_n/q_n}{t_n} = 1$$
On a last note. Consider that in order to prove the theorem, I don't really need to show that this holds for all sequences; I just need to show that this construction, with these properties, is feasible.
The sequence $\{t_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is given, and I cannot change it; but I have freedom over the sequences $\{p_n \, / \, q_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $\{a_n \, / \, b_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$.
Considering these two are sequences of rational approximations, maybe we can leverage on that, by constructing "particularly nice rational approximations", or approximation with a very fast rate of convergence; whatever that means.
Thanks in advance.

I'll admit I don't know what the best adjective/qualifier is for sequences such that $|u_n - v_n| \to 0$, but usually "equivalent" is reserved for the case where $u_n / v_n \to 1$, written as $u_n \sim v_n$, at least in the Landau notation which is quite common among analysts.

Anyway, the problem with this notion is that it's weaker for vanishing sequences than regular equivalence, as the limit of any two sequences $u$ and $v$ with limit $0$ satisfy $|u_n - v_n| \to 0$, it's a simple consequence of the triangle inequality: $$|u_n - v_n| \leq |u_n| + |v_n|$$ If you had the same but with sequences diverging to infinity then you would have the desired outcome by multiplying both sides by $t_n^{-1}$ which would tend to $0$ and thus be bounded.

Having just realised how to fix your problem, I regret having written two long comments instead of adding that info to this answer, but oh well. Either way it's available for now at least.
Anyway, since your choice of rational approximation can be arbitrary, you only need to tweak your selection by picking one such that:
$$\left|\frac{p_n}{q_n} - t_n\right| \leq t_n^2$$
You can replace the RHS by $t_n$ times any vanishing sequence really.
Now, dividing by $t_n$ yields:
$$0 \leq \left|\frac{p_n/q_n}{t_n} - 1\right| \leq t_n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{} 0$$
And you'll have the desired equivalence in the sense most analysts are used to, i.e. the limit of the ratios goes to $1$, rather than just your equivalence which I don't know if there is a standard name for sadly.

Yes! Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.
I have added the real-analysis and nomenclature tags too, hoping that maybe some other analysts can give us some clarification on how these situations are called. I used the word 'equivalent' to say that the sequence of the distances has limit zero, taking inspiration from this thread.

In addition to Bruno B's already perfect answer, I have decided to add an insight a friend of mine (a numerical analyst) also had to say.
The solution is essentially identical to that of Bruno B, but framed a little different.
Remember that we have freedom on the sequence $\{p_n \; / \; q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$.
Without loss of generality, my friend assumes that the sequence $\{p_n \; / \; q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ approximates $\{t_n \}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ form above, so that the quantity $p_n \; / \; q_n - t_n$ is always positive.
We want that:
$$ \frac{p_n \; / \; q_n}{t_n} \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{} 1.$$
We add and take away $t_n$:
$$ \frac{p_n \; / \; q_n - t_n}{t_n} + 1 \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{} 1,$$
but the latter is equivalent to saying that
$$ \frac{p_n \; / \; q_n - t_n}{t_n} \xrightarrow[n\to \infty]{} 0,$$
which by definition means that
$p_n \; / \; q_n - t_n = o(t_n)$, for $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Basically, the sought after property is that $\{p_n \; / \; q_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a little-oh of $t_n$.
As Bruno B correclty pointed out, $t_n^2 = o(t_n).$
Lastly, just for the sake of completeness, I would like to show how I completed the proof.
It turned out that the squeeze theorem wasn't the right tool - or at least, I couldn't use it.
As already discussed in the question, from the information we know have, we have basically already proven that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{q_n}{p_n}t_n = \lambda.$$
We are left  to prove that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} m_n t_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big \lfloor \frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{q_n}{p_n} \Big \rfloor t_n = \lambda.$$
Here's how I did: if we use curly braces to denote the fractional part, then:
$$ \lfloor x \rfloor = x - \{ x\}.$$
So:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} m_n t_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big \lfloor \frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{q_n}{p_n} \Big \rfloor t_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big ( \frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{q_n}{p_n} - \Big \{ \frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{q_n}{p_n} \Big \} \Big ) t_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{q_n}{p_n} t_n - \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big \{ \frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{q_n}{p_n} \Big \} t_n = \lambda - 0.$$
Of the last equality, the first limit equals $\lambda$ because it's the one we just calculated. The other one equals $0$ by the fact that the curly braces always return a bounded sequence, lying in $[0;1]$. So the last limit contains a bounded sequence, times a sequence whose limit is zero. Thus the limit of the product is zero.
Alternatively, to evaluate the last limit, one could indeed use the squeeze theorem. Since
$$ 0 \leq \Big \{ \frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{q_n}{p_n} \Big \} \leq 1,$$
we deduce that
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} 0 \cdot t_n \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} \Big \{ \frac{a_n}{b_n}\frac{q_n}{p_n} \Big \} t_n \leq \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 \cdot t_n.$$
